# Remove Spaces and HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

Trying to make sure no one put a space in the username on sign up, I got the html tags to removed but not spaces.

Javascript:

```
$("#user").keypress(function (evt) {
    if (isValid(String.fromCharCode(evt.which)))
        return false;
});

function isValid(str) {
    return /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}

function stripspaces(input) {
    input.value = input.value.replace(/\s/gi, "");
    return true;
}
```

HTML:

```
Username: <input type="text" id="user"><br/>
```

You can see it here. http://jsfiddle.net/QshDd/63/

Answer (score 1):

You can try with (each space character is being replaced, character by character, with the empty string):

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

or (each contiguous string of space characters is being replaced with the empty string by the "+" character):

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the input value with the spaces removed:

```
function stripspaces(input)
{
  return input.value.replace(/\s/gi,"");
}
```

The way you had it written the function just returned `true` regardless. Also, it seems you weren't calling the function (admittedly from only a quick read).

Although, it's probably easier to simply add `\s` (a regular expression special character for white-space characters) to the characters to replace, giving:

```
function isValid(str) {
    return /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/\s{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QshDd/68/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
input.value.replace(/\n/g," ").replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
```